# Terminal close on paste

Tags: shell, ubuntu, terminal, paste

everytime I execute a paste command (ctrl+v or mouswheel-click) in an open terminal its closing.
Things I've already done:

- turn off and on again -> same result
- change key-binings -> same result with other shortcut
- uninstall terminator -> same result with LXTerminal
- ! open ssh connection -> **no close**

I have ZSH installed ... maybe thats important. I do not know what to do.

Comment: Does it happen even if you select some text which dos not contain a newline - for example some arbitrary characters which you copy from an opened file in the text editor? It does not need to be a meaningful command, just to see whether maybe something is wrong with your clipboard.

Comment: Yes it also happens if I just copy & paste just an a.